# Postgresql pool with java pool?

Tags: java, postgresql

thanks if anybody can help me with this.

I'm newbie in postgres and java, but i have to implement an aplicattion that use an Jms listening a udp port, getting info about devices.

The problem is that for now we are doing test with nearly about 10.000, but the real amount is close to 100.000, sending info each five minutes.  So, I know i have to implement a pool like pgPool or pgBouncer, but I not sure if anyway i have to implement a connection pool in the java side, something like tomcat DBCP, o its enough with the pool in the postgres side.

ty a lot for help.

Comment: This isn't a great job to give a new developer! Please don't rely on writing direct to the database. You might need downtime for maintenance, upgrades, etc. Instead write data as it is received to a local spool file. Periodically rotate the spool file and then bulk-insert it into the database.

Comment: Ty for answer.  Its not an option to do that in a spool, since the aplication needs to check the last inserted record before inserted a new one for every device, in order to find signal errors between each record.  By now i can process more or less 200 connections per minute, but in a short time the company gonna buy a R720, so i think that i can improve the amount of transactions, cause they want to add more devices and send info each minute at least.  That's why I want a pool.